# Metamask complaining about synchronous method even with callback parameter

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask

I'm getting a

> The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_gasPrice without a callback parameter.

even though I'm providing that callback parameter:

```
web3.eth.gasPrice((err, gasPrice) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    store.dispatch('pollWeb3', {gasPrice: gasPrice})
  }
})
```

According to [the doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgasprice) this should be working. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If used with a callback, the method name must be `web3.eth.getGasPrice(...`